# QuestDB Line Protocol

Tags: questdb

I'm using the NodeJS demo code from here: https://questdb.io/docs/develop/insert-data/ to insert data into QuestDB like this:

```
   setInterval(() => {
        run();
    }, 3000);
```

(2 Docker containers on a bridge network)

And I have a browser window open to run

```
select count(*) from 'trades'
```

However, the query only runs once and then returns the same result. If I restart the docker containers, the query returns an updated value so I assume the values are successfully getting into the database but they are not reflected in the Postgres queries. I see the same behavior when I use the pg client in Node.

Any explanation or theory that would help me root cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In QDB data is not visible to queries until it's committed .
In case of ILP receiver commits don't happen after each row or even on disconnect . Instead QDB uses a number of properties to determine when to commit efficiently .
In this case the easiest way to reduce insert to commit delay would be to reduce cairo.max.uncommitted.rows to e.g. 10 in conf/server.conf (plus instance/container restart) and then insert 10+ records .

You'll find more details on ILP commits at
https://questdb.io/docs/reference/api/ilp/tcp-receiver/#commit-strategy

Comment: Thank you, kind of what I thought. I'm wondering if QDB is a viable product then to show live data if data can't be queried until it is committed to disk. InfluxDB doesn't seem to have this limitation.

Comment: It all depends on how frequently you plan to commit . If data is ordered then you could commit even every couple of rows and everything would be fine . If data is not ordered then committing too frequently could reduce ingestion performance . Note that commit doesn't mean that data is stored to disk because writes are asynchronous . It's explained  at questdb.io/docs/concept/storage-model/#append-model . Like many databases QDB doesn't support dirty reads so I wouldn't consider this behavior a 'limitation' .

Comment: By the way - I'm no expert in IDB but here's an excerpt from its documentation : "if the ingest rate is high (multiple writes per ms), query results may not include the most recent data." –